# Vuejs with vue-routes Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have updated my vue js application from version v1.0 to v3.0.1 and since then i always receives an exception (detail exception message is below) when calling a new router path.

This is how my main.js look like:

```
require('es6-shim')

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '../i18n/messages'
import store from './store'
import App from './App'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

import DemoshopCartPage from 'components/DemoshopCartPage'
import DemoshopSuccessPage from 'components/DemoshopSuccessPage'
import DemoshopCancelPage from 'components/DemoshopCancelPage'
import DemoshopErrorPage from 'components/DemoshopErrorPage'
import DemoshopConfirmOrderPage from 'components/DemoshopConfirmOrderPage'
import DemoshopAdditionalFieldsModal from 'components/DemoshopAdditionalFieldsModal'
import DemoshopSeamlessLogsModal from 'components/DemoshopSeamlessLogsModal'
import DemoshopIntegrationCodeModal from 'components/DemoshopIntegrationCodeModal'
import DemoshopPaymentParametersModal from 'components/DemoshopPaymentParametersModal'
import DemoshopIntegrationCodeForConfirmationModal from 'components/DemoshopIntegrationCodeForConfirmationModal'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages
})

let modalsRoutes = [{
  path: 'additional-fields',
  component: DemoshopAdditionalFieldsModal
},
  {
    path: 'additional-fields/:tab',
    component: DemoshopAdditionalFieldsModal
  },
  {
    path: 'seamless-logs',
    component: DemoshopSeamlessLogsModal
  },
  {
    path: 'integration-code',
    component: DemoshopIntegrationCodeModal
  },
  {
    path: 'payment-parameters',
    component: DemoshopPaymentParametersModal
  },
  {
    path: 'integration-code-confirm',
    component: DemoshopIntegrationCodeForConfirmationModal
  }
]

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/cart', component: DemoshopCartPage, children: modalsRoutes},
    {path: '/success', component: DemoshopSuccessPage, children: modalsRoutes},
    {path: '/cancel', component: DemoshopCancelPage, children: modalsRoutes},
    {path: '/error', component: DemoshopErrorPage, children: modalsRoutes},
    {path: '/confirmOrder', component: DemoshopConfirmOrderPage, children: modalsRoutes},
    {path: '/', redirect: '/cart'}
  ]
})

sync(store, router)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#demoApp',
  components: {App},
  router,
  i18n,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

And this are my html source, which i use in the vue component:

```
 <template>
  <div class="dev-toolbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="cart-action">
        <router-link :to="'additional-fields'" title="Additional fields" append>
          <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> fields
        </router-link>
      </li> ....
```

When clicking on the link I receive always this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1320), <anonymous>:279:34)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:2001:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HashHistory.updateRoute (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:2000:26)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:1877:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:1986:7)
    at step (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:1716:7)
    at runQueue (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:1727:3)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:1981:5)
    at step (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2922), <anonymous>:1716:7)
```

It is also get the same exception in console log, when i try to call it via a method like:

```
callPush() {
     this.$router.push('additional-fields')
  },
```

This dependencies i am using in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-runtime": "^6.0.0",
"dot-object": "1.4.1",
"es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
"font-awesome": "4.6.3",
"highlight.js": "^9.7.0",
"jquery": "3.0.0",
"lodash": "4.13.1",
"query-string": "4.2.2",
"vue": "2.5.17",
"vue-i18n": "7.4.2",
"vue-multiselect": "2.1.0",
"vue-resource": "1.3.6",
"vue-router": "3.0.1",
"vuex": "3.0.1",
"vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
},
```

Nevertheless the correct page is opening successufully. I just want to get rid of this error

Comment: After adding the "name" parameter to the routes and running npm install again it is working now

Answer (score 0):

The router runs on route names.  You need to name your routes.

```js
let modalsRoutes = [
  {
    name: 'additional-fields',
    path: 'additional-fields',
    component: DemoshopAdditionalFieldsModal
  },
  {
    name: 'additional-fields-tab',
    path: 'additional-fields/:tab',
    component: DemoshopAdditionalFieldsModal
  },
  {
    name: 'seamless-logs',
    path: 'seamless-logs',
    component: DemoshopSeamlessLogsModal
  },
  {
    name: 'integration-code',
    path: 'integration-code',
    component: DemoshopIntegrationCodeModal
  },
  {
    name: 'payment-parameters',
    path: 'payment-parameters',
    component: DemoshopPaymentParametersModal
  },
  {
    name: 'integration-code-confirm',
    path: 'integration-code-confirm',
    component: DemoshopIntegrationCodeForConfirmationModal
  }
]
```

also, your template is incorrect.  Your route does'nt need the `'` around the name:

```html
<template>
  <div class="dev-toolbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="cart-action">
        <router-link :to="additional-fields" title="Additional fields" append>
          <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> fields
        </router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thx for your advice. I added name for all routes, but still get the same exception